# Using Wildcard in If Statement with Cell Reference

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation, wildcard

I'm building a worksheet that will concatenate cells based off of criteria in another column on the same row. After much searching I found Harlan Groves aconcat UDF and this is the formula I've got so far:

=SUBSTITUTE(aconcat(IF(Labor!$A$8:$A$100=A2," "&Labor!$M$8:$M$100," "))," ","",1)

Labor!A8:A100 looks like this:

- 115012ABCD
- 115013ZYWX
- 115014WASD
- 121018ABCD
- 121018WASD

Cell A2 = 115

Cell B2 has the formula above.

I'm trying to concatenate a summary of all cells that start with the first three digits of the number in Labor!A8:A100. I've got the formula mostly working but my cell reference (A2) is causing me issues. If I use the exact match (e.g. 115012ABCD) in cell A2, my formula works. Otherwise it returns no data.

How can I tell Excel to find values that start with the digits in cell A2 rather than have to be an exact match with cell A2?